# Does this distribution with polynomial tails have a name?

Tags: extreme-value, distribution-identification

I have $N$ random variables which are identically and independently distributed with complementary CDF:

$$Pr[X \geq x] = \frac{a}{X} + \frac{b}{X^2}$$
for $x \geq 1/2 \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b} + a/2$.

This functional form is a bit annoying to them. At the end of the day I care about the maximum value
$$Z_n = \max(X_1,...,X_n)$$
of my Random variables.

My two questions are

1. Does this distribution have a name?
2. Is it in the Frechet domain of attraction? What linear transformation is required to make the extreme value theorem apply?

Comment: By inspection, when $a\gt 0$ one is strongly tempted to normalize the max by dividing by $a n,$ because $$\left(1-\frac{a}{anx}-\frac{b}{(anx)^2}\right)^n\approx\exp(-(x^{-1})).$$ You may continue from there.

Comment: Re question (1): This distribution can be expressed as a mixture of two [Pareto distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).

Comment: Such a distribution is in the Fréchet domain and even more: it is *tail equivalent* to a Pareto or to a GPD or GEV with shape $\xi = -1$.